# Can a vertical multiwatt package be bent to lie horizontal after it is installed?

Tags: components, component-selection, packages, mechanical, mechanical-assembly

I am working on a project with a [multiwatt package audio amplifier IC.](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1811011614_STMicroelectronics-TDA7294V_C10068.pdf)

Can this component be bent over to lie horizontal, flush with the PCB, after it is soldered into place?

Comment: ((For multiple watts it would need cooling.) If I was to bend it, I would bend *before soldering.)

Comment: Because the pins are in two offset rows, it is essential that any bending is done before soldering. Were I to attempt such a thing, I would ensure that all bends were done with the pin held rigidly very close to the package to avoid any strain on the interior. I would advise against this procedure.

Comment: Flat heatsinks are not as good as vertical heatsinks. This needs to be factored in.

Comment: They make this same component in a horizontal package but it is much more expensive for some reason, and my manufacturer does not stock it, which is why I want to just bend the horizontal one over

Comment: @Andyaka My plan it to have a large exposed copped area with vias and use that for heatsinking, with the potential to screw an additional heatsink to the back of the board if more cooling is required

Comment: That part sheds a lot of heat. Normally, it's mounted on a horizontal PCB, and the part attaches to a heatsink at the back of the chassis where it has good natural convection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’m going to assume you have a very tight space requirement that’s leading you to consider this, and somehow you’ve got a plan for the heatsink for this lay-flat orientation.

As for your question, it’s a bad idea. The lead frame or the encapsulation is likely to crack if you bend it over flat. This is due to the bend stress being concentrated at the lead-package interface.

Instead, consider a small PCB interposer to adapt the power package to horizontal.

Answer (score 2):

No, a vertical multiwatt package cannot be bent to lie horizontal after installation due to the rigid nature of its internal components.